# what is difference between query string vs wildcard in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can you please tell me when to use query string and when to use wildcard. 
In the below scenario what should I use

```
POST _search
{
  "query": { 
    "filtered": { 
      "query": [{
        "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "afDeparture"
                ],
            "query": "16feb*"
            }
        }],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "boardPoint": "dxb" }}, 
        { "range": { "localDeparture": { "gte": 1454270400000 }}} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Query_String value is parsed with a query parser to get the actual query
  Like `name:this AND surname:that`
- But the wildcard query is a term level query that only evaluates the `*` and `?`

To sum up **query_string**'s value is also a `query` to be parsed  but **wildcard_query** value is an `expression`

Your query can be

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
           "afDeparture": {
              "value": "16feb*"
           }
        },
        "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "boardPoint": "dxb" }}, 
        { "range": { "localDeparture": { "gte": 1454270400000 }}} 
      ]
    }
}
```